# iPhone : How to set BackgroundColor of UIButton with buttonType UIButtonTypeCustom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i want to change the button color when it is clicked. I used :

```
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but this shows red color only on the four corners of button not on the whole button and also when i use `forState:UIControlStateNormal` then the application hangs.
Is their any way to show some color on button when clicked?

```
[click1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 38):

You could create an image programmatically and so have the ability to use your colors in a dynamic way:

Create a category for UIButton with this method and be sure to have QuartzCore lib imported via `@import QuartzCore`:

```
- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    colorView.backgroundColor = color;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(colorView.bounds.size);
    [colorView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setBackgroundImage:colorImage forState:state];
}
```

This is gonna create an image with the size of your button for your specified color and then assigning it for the wished state. Because of the usage of the backgroundImage you can still set a title for the button via the setTitle:forState: method.

Comment: about your NOTE: Or you can just use `-[UIButton setBackgroundImage:forState]` method with `-[UIButton setTitle:forState:]`. Thanks for the recipe!

Comment: This is a great answer. But I would change the `[self setImage:colorImage forState:state];`to `[self setBackgroundImage:colorImage forState:state];` this way you can still see the title of the button.

Comment: This is a good answer.  Another thing I would suggest is to create a 1x1 pixel image instead, as it will use far less memory and UIButton stretches the background image by default anyway.  `UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];` is how I did it.

Comment: I have used this same code, but it is not working for me

Answer (score 14):

This is what I do ... it's a custom subclass of a UIButton, just set the normal and highlighted colors and everything shpould work fine ;)

Header file:

```
//
//  FTCustomButton.h
//  FTLibrary
//
//  Created by Ondrej Rafaj on 14/01/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Fuerte International. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FTCustomButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIColor *normalColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIColor *highlightedColor;

- (void)setNormalColor:(UIColor *)normalColor;
- (void)setHighlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor;


@end
```

This is the implementation file:

```
//
//  FTCustomButton.m
//  FTLibrary
//
//  Created by Ondrej Rafaj on 14/01/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Fuerte International. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FTCustomButton.h"

//*****************************************************************************
// private interface declaration
//*****************************************************************************
@interface MCSelectionButton ()
    @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIColor *normalColor;
    @property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIColor *highlightedColor;
@end

//*****************************************************************************
// public interface implementation
//*****************************************************************************

@implementation FTCustomButton


#pragma mark Settings

- (void)setNormalColor:(UIColor *)normalColor {
    [self setBackgroundColor:normalColor];
    _normalColor = normalColor;
}

- (void)setHighlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor {
    _highlightedColor = highlightedColor;
}

#pragma mark Actions

- (void)didTapButtonForHighlight:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self setBackgroundColor:_highlightedColor];
}

- (void)didUnTapButtonForHighlight:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self setBackgroundColor:_normalColor];
}

#pragma mark Initialization

- (void)setupButton {
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButtonForHighlight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(didUnTapButtonForHighlight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(didUnTapButtonForHighlight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setupButton];
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Comment: @cabellicar123 I think your proposed edit should have been a comment.

Comment: If you press the button and drag your finger out of the selection range, than the color of the button remains "_highlightedColor" while it no longer highlighted.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure the button type is custom as someone else already stated.  Then doing the following will bring back those rounded corners:

```
 [self.myButton.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
 [self.myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
 [self.myButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
 [self.myButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
 self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Though, personally, I'm a big fan of gradient buttons over solid colors... also, background color doesn't have different states, whereas background images do:

```
 [self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Using an image, your button will darken with selection (or you could provide a different background image per state to do something different).  This won't happen with background color, the background will always stay the same, only your button label changing per state.

Answer (score 7):

Completing Dima answer, I've implemented an extension in Swift:

```
extension UIButton {
    private func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forUIControlState state: UIControlState) {
        self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color), forState: state)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe a more efficient solution than any of the ones listed is to just draw the image in Core Graphics directly. You avoid having to make a `UIView` and calling `renderInContext:`, [which can be pretty slow](http://damir.me/ios7-blurring-techniques).

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

You can use this in a `UIImage` category to create an image to use in a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 2):

you have take a red color image for your button and then you can set it when user clicks

```
[yourButtonName setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourRedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: but i dont want to use an image only color when button is clicked

Comment: there is no method like what you trying

Answer (score 2):

To get a button with a single color you can set the button to custom button.
Here is my known list of available button api (you can set them in viewDidLoad after setting them as outlets).
Just import quartz and change the border radius to make it look like a button.

```
//highlightcolor - this changes the status for UIControlStateHighlighted
OUTLETNAME.tintColor =  [UIColor orangeColor];

//borderradius *quartz
[[OUTLETNAME layer] setCornerRadius:20.0f];

//border *quartz
[[OUTLETNAME layer] setBorderWidth:5.0f];

//bordercolor
[OUTLETNAME.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];

//backgroundcolor 
OUTLETNAME.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

//image 
[OUTLETNAME setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PICNAME] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//text 
[OUTLETNAME setTitle:@"TEXT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//fontsize
OUTLETNAME.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36.0];

//fontcolor
OUTLETNAME.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

//fontcolor
[OUTLETNAME setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you want custom buttons with a gradient color you have to make a custom button class.

This blog has a glossy button class project for download.
http://didikot.com/?p=217

You have to refractor and convert to ARC to use it, I think.

This blog does the same thing but without the gloss.
http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Answer (score 1):

@pankaj Gyani says correct

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(prevButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IntroArrowLeft.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:button];
```

Comment: You can edit your own post,instead of answering multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You should set UIButton's type to custom and set its image or background image properties for normal and highlighted states.

For professional and nice looking buttons that you can easily use in your apps [this](http://www.binpress.com/app/glossy-button-for-ios/968) custom button component may also help.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything correct. Just set your button type to UIButtonTypeCustom..

```
button =    [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame    =   CGRectMake(200, 8, 100, 30);
[button setTitle:@"Set up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
button.clipsToBounds    =   YES;
button.layer.cornerRadius   =   10;
button.alpha        =   0.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to Hendrik answer.

To work well with Auto Layout you need to set UIView frame size to button intrinsicContentSize, otherwise it will screw up layout.

```
- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.intrinsicContentSize.width, self.intrinsicContentSize.height)];
    colorView.backgroundColor = color;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(colorView.bounds.size);
    [colorView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setBackgroundImage:colorImage forState:state];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the button type as custom.

Eg

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

All the best.

Comment: but custom removes the round cornered button .i think nobody will want this i think i have to use image instead which i never wabted to use

Comment: Even if you use image, you should make button type as custom for good look.Feel the difference.Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dima

Here is an updated code for swift 3.0 as UIButton extension

```
extension UIButton {
  // thanks to @Dima http://stackoverflow.com/a/24665476/2581637 update code for swift 3
  func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forUIControlState state: UIControlState) {
    func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
      let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
      if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)
      }

      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

      return image
    }

    self.setBackgroundImage(imageWithColor(color: color), for: state)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. In .xib -  set Button Type: Custom.
2. Set Background Color as per you want.

Answer (score -2):

```
 UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


 [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: This dosen not set a colour for a state