# Custom UI Button touch event Background Color

Tags: uibutton

I have a **custom UIButton that the touch event** isn't quite right for.  I need the Background Color to change immediately when the button is touched up inside.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)buttonOneWithTeam:(id)sender {
    if
    ([tNLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Hi"]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"button" sender:sender];
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"web" sender:sender];
    }
    [buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOnePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

- (IBAction)buttonOnePressed:(id)sender {
    [buttonOne setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

When I press the button, the background color doesn't get changed until the ViewController is already firing to the next ViewController.  Or if I hold a button down, it won't change color immediately when held like it should.

**And what I need is for it to change color immediately when it is held down or pressed, and also change color back to once the button is not being held down anymore.**  Any ideas?

Comment: Just a tip: most people would watch iOS and objective-c tags. So make sure to tag your question with them.

Comment: @MohannadA.Hassan thanks for the tip so I can get more eyes that need to be on it, on it!  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default event triggered when you connect a button in your Storyboard or IB to your IBAction method is *touch up inside*, which means the method will be called when you tap the button and lift up your finger while it is inside the area (and a bit of its surrounding) of the button.

You can take a look at the last tab in your Utilities section for the connections of the button.

[image: Touch up inside]

As you can see, there are many other events that can be connected to the button. One of them is *touch down* which you might be interested in when you want to change the background color of a button the moment you hold down a button.

Just link the IBAction method to the *touch down* event. Or you can use the code:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

But then you might also want to consider what should happen to the background color when the user *touch down enter*, *touch down inside*, *touch down outside*, *touch up outside*, etc.

Comment: Makes perfect sense!  Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: Quick question, what sort of code would I use for just changing the button color to `greenColor` when touch down event happens?  Because for button I set the background color to `blackColor`.  So my question is, what would I use for setting the background color for `UIControlEventTouchDown` to `greenColor`?

Comment: @Reez I think for changing background color, you will need to subclass the UIButton. Or just make use of the background image and set differently for different state. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049103/iphone-how-to-set-backgroundcolor-of-uibutton-with-buttontype-uibuttontypecust