# UIButton UIControlEventTouchUpOutside Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a custom UIButton. To create a custom background color when highlighted I the button (self) as an observer to three events:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButtonForHighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(didUnTapButtonForHighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(didUnTapButtonForHighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

The first two work beautifully, and as long as I touch up inside the button the background gets set back to normal. However if I touch up outside the button the method `didUnTapButtonForHighlight` never gets called and the background remains the highlighted color. My code is a modified version of the code in Ondrej's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049103/iphone-how-to-set-backgroundcolor-of-uibutton-with-buttontype-uibuttontypecust). Why is it not working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also test for `UIControlEventTouchCancel` in case you touch up way outside.

Comment: How far is way outside? Why don't they just make it outside? Thanks for the help though. Works great now. I'll accept your answer when it lets me.

Comment: I don't think the distance is documented anywhere. It's probably about 60-70 pixels around the button. It just allows the user to cancel a button press after they already touched down. A touch up outside within that range is suppose to still trigger the button.

Comment: Just stumbled upon the same problem. The "distance" seems to be related to the view frame the button is contained in. If the drag is moving out of the superview's bounds, UIControlEventTouchCancel will be fired. (iOS 7.1)