# UIActionSheet Selected background Color in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

In my app , i have a lot of value to choice , So i used `UIActionSheet` to show.

So the following pic is appear.

[image]

As you see , the selected row `Color` is `Blue`.

I want to change that color to `Gray`.

How can i change it?

Comment: Try adding a blue color image or layer to the button as background when selected..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4049103/1059705

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{

        //Gets an array af all of the subviews of our actionSheet
        NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];

        for (UIView *v in subviews) 
        {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
            {
                UIButton *b = (UIButton*)v;
                [b setBackgroundImageByColor:[UIColor gray] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted ];
            }
        }   
}
```

try this code..

Comment: There is no setBackgroundImageByColor method bro. that error showing

Comment: set actionsheet delegate in .h

Comment: find out [b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor gray] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted ]; property

Comment: Can you link to that method of UIButton setBackgroundColor:forState:.? @JitendraDeore

Comment: There is no that method in UIButton bro. setBackgroundColor only is for UIColor , not with ForState Property.