# Override setBackgroundColor of an UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've created a custom button class that inherit from UIButton but I cannot override the `setBackgroundColor` setter.

When I do

```
@synthesize backgroundColor = _backgroundColor;

...

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    _backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    // Custom code
}
```

I get an error on the `@synthesize` line

> Property declared in category 'UIViewRendering' cannot be implemented in class implementation

Here is the complete code :

FlatButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FlatButton : UIButton

@end
```

FlatButton.m

```
#import "FlatButton.h"

@implementation FlatButton

@synthesize backgroundColor = _backgroundColor;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    _backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    // I want to do stuff here
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you declaring the @interface in the m file?

Comment: No, the @interface block is only in my .h file

Comment: Can you add it here? I suspect your class is a category and not a class extension

Comment: Your designated ivar/property is clashing with one created by UIKit. use a different name.

Comment: Try to set background color by providing controlState also..ie. [btn setBackgroundColor:clr withCintrlState:state];

Comment: @mattsven : My only property is `shadowOffset`but when I remove this property (and all the code related), I still get the same issue. 

@Ashutosh : UIButton do not provide a `setBackgroundColor:forState`. I have added a category to do that but I don't see how this should resolve a compilation error on a `synthesize`

Comment: That's odd. Did you clean?

Comment: I think you cannot use _backgroundColor since it is not a property of UIButton. you can override the setter and use some custom properties for backgroundColor and highlightedBackgroundColor like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14320408/3659846