# How to change title color and background color of dynamic UIButton when clicked and first button should be selected as default?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view and I created some 8 dynamic buttons programmatically in that. The title color of buttons is white color. I want to change color of button title to green color when it is clicked. And if i click any other button, the previously clicked button title color should become white and current button title color should become green.

I have used the following code and its working properly for changing the color of previous button and now I want the first button to be in selected mode as default and first button should be changed when another button is clicked.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

_examsListDict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
_examsListDict1[@"Exam Name"] = @"JEE Mains";
.........so on another 4 dictionaries

_examsListArray = [[NSMutableArray   
alloc]initWithObjects:_examsListDict1,_examsListDict2,_examsListDict3,_examsListDict4,_examsListD
ict5, nil];
NSUInteger i;
int xCoord=0;
int yCoord=0;
int buttonWidth=120;
int buttonHeight=50;
int buffer = 1;

for (i = 0; i <[_examsListArray count]; i++)
{
    aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.frame     = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
    [aButton setTitle:[[_examsListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Exam Name"]       
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTag:i];
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f 
    blue:221.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_buttonsHorizontalScrollView addSubview:aButton];
     xCoord += buttonWidth + buffer;
    }
    [_buttonsHorizontalScrollView   
    setContentSize:CGSizeMake(aButton.frame.size.width*_examsListArray.count+203, yCoord)];
    }

    - (void)whatever:(id)sender
   {

   UIButton *tempBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
   [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f 
   blue:221.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
   aButton = tempBtn;
   [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:133.0f/255.0f green:169.0f/255.0f 
   blue:83.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
   }
```

No I just want the first button to be selected as default when the view is loaded and whenever I select the other button it should change to deselected color.

```
   if ([aButton tag] == 0)
 {
  [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
  [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:133.0f/255.0f green:169.0f/255.0f 
  blue:83.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
  }
```

I have used the above code to select as first button as default but first button is not getting changed when other button is clicked and it is changing only when the first button is clicked again due to this aButton = tempBtn.How to do that?

Comment: specify the title colour for the selected state, in an IBAction method set the sender to selected and all the other buttons to deselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to set the selected status title color of all your buttons and then add them to an array. Then when you press one of them just change their status, no need to handle colors or keep track of the currently selected button.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *yourButtons;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _examsListDict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    _examsListDict1[@"Exam Name"] = @"JEE Mains";
    .........so on another 4 dictionaries

    _examsListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:_examsListDict1,_examsListDict2,_examsListDict3,_examsListDict4,_examsListDict5, nil];
    NSUInteger i;
    int xCoord=0;
    int yCoord=0;
    int buttonWidth=120;
    int buttonHeight=50;
    int buffer = 1;


    // Generate background images
    //
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:221.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    UIImage *selectedBackgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:133.0f/255.0f green:169.0f/255.0f blue:83.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];


    // Initialize your array
    //
    self.yourButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (i = 0; i < [_examsListArray count]; i++) {

        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord,buttonWidth,buttonHeight );
        [aButton setTitle:[[_examsListArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Exam Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setTag:i];
        [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:selectedColorImage forState:UIControlStateSelected]
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_buttonsHorizontalScrollView addSubview:aButton];
        xCoord += buttonWidth + buffer;

        // Select the first one
        //
        if (i == 0)
            aButton.selected = YES;


        // Add your newly created button to the array
        //
        [self.yourButtons addObject:aButton];
    }
    [_buttonsHorizontalScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(aButton.frame.size.width*_examsListArray.count+203, yCoord)];

}

- (void)whatever:(id)sender {

   for (UIButton *button in self.yourButtons) {

       // Toggle selected flag
       //
       button.selected = button == sender;
   }
}


+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {

    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/24665476/1835155
    //
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine for changing the title colors but I want to change the background color of selected button and remaining buttons in normal color and also first button should be in selected mode whenever the view is opened as I don't  want to display empty data in the view.

Comment: I did what you said in the above and its working good until there is no button click i mean i gave a dark color for selection and light color for deselection at first the first button is in selection mode with dark background color and when any other button or the first button is clicked the light color is becoming the section mode and darker color for deselection.

Comment: @GopalaKrishnaKammela I'm not sure to understand what you're saying but I edited my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Small correction in code it should be button.selected = YES; in place of button.selected = !button.selected; otherwise if the selected button is selected again it is showing as deselected.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the first button state when another button is clicked you have to "fake" a touch event. In the selector method of the other button do this:

For Example:

```
-(void)thirdButtonClicked:(id) sender
{
    [firstButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: How to call a first button as iam creating buttons dynamically?

Comment: You can put the buttons in an array as you create them dynamically. Once you do that, all you need to do is grab the first object in the array which will be your first button and do whatever you need with it

Answer (score 0):

TRUEThe unpressed button is UIControlStateNormal while the pressed button is UIControlStateSelected  so set the colours you want based on the State. You typically do this in ViewDidload before anyone has a chance to use it -  Below is a sample setup:

```
 button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setSelected:YES];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

I believe what you should be doing when the trigger button is clicked is to just set the state to selected

```
- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
  if (sender == trigger_button) {
   [button setHighlighted:TRUE];
   [button setSelected:TRUE];
}
```