# Can't set background color of a UIButton when selected?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uikit

In a UIButton subclass:

```
- (void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if (selected) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //this happens
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```

I see the red color when the button is highlighted. But when I set button.selected = YES, I never see a green color. Why does setHighlighted work but setSelected doesn't?

I can set a breakpoint on the "this happens" line, and it happens. But the background color of the button doesn't change to green.

Comment: What attributes do you have set in interface builder?

Comment: there are a couple of answers out there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049103/iphone-how-to-set-backgroundcolor-of-uibutton-with-buttontype-uibuttontypecust it looks like one common solution is to set a background image that is basically a 1x1 pixel of a color. This solution works because you set the background image for each specific state. I'm not really sure why your code doesnt work. does the button get unselected right after it gets selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the `selected` property inside your button's UIControlEventTouchUpInside action? If so, your `setHighlighted:` method is getting called again after `setSelected:`, so `backgroundColor` is being set back to blue.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what's happening. Do you know of any workarounds for this?

Comment: I'd probably just add an `updateBackgroundColor` (or something) method that checks both states, and then call that method from the overridden setters.